# Book series with parallel earths and a secret governmental agency

Tags: story-identification, books

What's the book series where there are secret pocket/parallel earths, and nobody knows that they live in a pocket/parallel earth?

The story is set in the present. The main character is from a parallel earth that enters the original earth, and is then recruited by the government to help investigate a possible nuclear event on another parallel earth.

The book series was read in 2019–2022. The titles of the book series, if I remember correctly, are always something along the lines of "Autumn in..."

An additional detail is that the government on the original earth knows about the parallel earths/pocket earths, and some of the pocket earths were created to complete science experiments that would be considered inhuman on the original earth. There is also a secret organization that tries to control all the pocket earths and the coming and going of different people from different earths.

One pocket earth is super advanced scientifically. Another pocket earth seems to be still living in the Victorian era.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the book series and what book series you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: The book series was read in 2019-2022.  The titles of the books series, if I remember correctly, are always something along the lines of 'Autumn in ..."

Comment: An additional detail is that the goverment on original earth knows about the parallel earths/pocket earths and some of the pocket earths were created to complete science experiments that would be considered inhuman on the original earth.  There is also a secret organizations that tries to control all the pocket earths and the going of different people from different earths.

Comment: One pocket earth is super advanced scientifically.  Another pocket earth seems to be still living in a Victorian-era

Comment: You can add more info by [edit]ing your question. Also, please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Comment: Is the "government" that recruits the main character the government of some real-world country like France or India, or is it the government of a fictional country, or a world government? Is the story set in the present or the future?

Comment: It's the English government.  Story is set in the present

Comment: Is it possible this is Dave Hutchinson's [Fractured Europe series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/179056-the-fractured-europe-sequence)? If so the book you are remembering is _Europe in Autumn_ not _Autumn in ..._ and the books all start _Europe in ..._. Some of the elements you mention are present in this series, though it's a bit different from your description.

Comment: I had a vague recollection, but it is the Fractured Europe series.  Thanks!

Comment: By "English" government, do you mean the UK government? Or actually "English"?

Comment: @R.Almas Thanks for confirming the identification.  I have added an answer. Please will you click the tick mark to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)

Comment: Shades of [*Counterpart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpart_(TV_series))!

Answer (score 12):

As confirmed in a comment, this is Dave Hutchinson's [Fractured Europe series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/179056-the-fractured-europe-sequence).

The book you remember is *Europe in Autumn*, and the books all start *Europe in ...*

[image: Europe in Autumn]

They were written from 2014 to 2018, which fits with the time you remember reading them.